# Wifi in Windows 8 kills itself after a second

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I have a problem with Windows 8.1 on my laptop.

Since about a week (I can't remember what modifications to software I did, but I'm *pretty sure* I changed nothing), when I boot or resume PC from sleep, I get wifi disconnected.

So I enable it and wait for it to connect. I click the wireless icon and switch `Enabled`. After about one second from that, during connection to my home router, wifi disconnects. The `Enabled` switch goes into disabled mode.

It takes a few back-and-forth with the two switches: `Enabled` and `Airplane Mode` to get things normal again.

But it's annoying.

When I talk about "switches" I obviously talk about software switches on Windows graphical interface, not hardware switches. My laptop is an ASUS N76VZ

Comment: Is Windows 64 bit? Which driver version are you currently using?

Comment: Yes, Windows x64. I tried to install @edvinas.me's suggested drivers but that didn't work. I installed a Windows Update-provided driver on 10/20/2013

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work, exactly? Did you get an error? Open the Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`), locate the Wi-Fi adapter and open its properties. Click the **Driver** tab and check the current version. Then click the **Details** tab and select the **Hardware Ids** property. Finally, post all information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Uninstall the driver from Device Manager and let Windows detect the device again.
Then, avoid updating drivers via Windows Update or any other means. While they work good, there is no need to change.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you got newer version of drivers via Windows Update. I had a few instances when these drivers were causing problems like you describe. I would redownload wifi drivers from official website and reinstall it.

You can find the drivers for your model here:

Windows 8 64bit:

http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=N76VZ&hashedid=0CXpcswToDWKckrh

Windows 8.1 64bit:

http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=N76VZ&hashedid=0CXpcswToDWKckrh

Comment: I tried to install the 64 bit driver but that didn't work. I checked Windows Update history and driver update for wifi happened on 10/20/2013 (Intel driver update for Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230)

Comment: Try making new account on windows and testing there. It is a very wild guess but will show if it could be anything to your profile configuration or any specific applications that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The driver issue let me to the solution, even without creating an account.

Comment: Could you please mark is as an answer then? Thank you and good to hear that you got it sorted.